# trying to concatenate commands to give a file path

Tags: linux, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate several commands to give a file path.

I need to run this:

`ls -l /proc/{PID}/fd/{FILE_NAME}`

I can get the PID by running:

`lsof | grep 'mysql\(.*\)deleted' | awk { print $2 }'`

And I can get the file name by running:

`lsof | grep 'mysql\(.*\)deleted' | awk { print $10 } | cut -d'/' -f3`

Both of those give me nice long lists, but how can I use them to generate the file path for the ls command?

Comment: Please show samples of the lists.

Comment: I have no way right now to copy them off the server anywhere but first is a line separated list of PIDs and second is a line seperated list of file names

Comment: Can the file names contain spaces?

Comment: the file names do not contain spaces no.

Comment: Try running ```lsof | grep 'deleted'``` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, you can use arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
pids=( $(lsof | grep 'mysql.*deleted' | awk '{ print $2 }') )
files=( $(lsof | grep 'mysql.*deleted' | awk '{ print $10 }' | cut -d/ -f3) )
for ((i=0; i<${#pids[@]}; i++)) ; do
    ls -l /proc/${pids[i]/fd/${files[i]}
done
```

Another possibility would be to read from two streams:

```
while read pid ; do
    read file <&3
    ls -l /proc/$pid/fd$file
done < <(lsof | grep 'mysql.*deleted' | awk '{ print $2 }') \
     3< <(lsof | grep 'mysql.*deleted' | awk '{ print $10 }' | cut -d'/' -f3)
```

Comment: @Chris: Check the update.